# How to pull all images in [body] Matrix fields

Tags: templating, matrix, field

I'm working on a basic portfolio site wherein each entry or "project" has a body Matrix field with various blocks for various types of images. I'd like to make an index of all projects showing one slideshow/carousel for each project containing all images within that project.

The problem is that I don't know how to query all images at once = All images, all blocks, in the order they appear in the entry.

Here's my specific code in use. It's almost there but due to the `0` in `image[0]` it's only pulling in the first image from each instance of each Matrix Block. For example, there are two instances of the block called `imageHalf` and it pulls the first image from each.

I don't understand how to avoid this integer....

```
{% for block in entry.body %}

{% switch block.type %}

{% case "imageFull" %}

{% set image = block.image.total() %}

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}"><img data-lazy="
        {{ block.image[0].getUrl() }}
    " /></a>

{% case "imageHalf" %}

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}"><img data-lazy="
        {{ block.image[0].getUrl() }}
    " /></a>

{% case "imageCouple" %}

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}"><img data-lazy="
        {{ block.image[0].getUrl() }}
    " /></a>

{% endswitch %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a `{% switch %}` statement like the following:

```
{% switch matrixBlock.type %}

{% case "text" %}

    {{ matrixBlock.textField | markdown }}

{% case "image" %}

    {{ matrixBlock.image[0].getImg() }}

{% default %}

    <p>A font walks into a bar.</p>
    <p>The bartender says, “Hey, we don’t serve your type in here!”</p>
{% endswitch %}
```

You can read more here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/switch

Comment: Right! This is actually what I was using (sorry I didn't add it before). To be more specific, I'm hung up on how it's only pulling the first image/asset and not the others. How do I avoid the `[0]` ?

Comment: @JeremyPaulBeasley Looks like Mmikkel beat me to it but you need to do something like

{% for image in block.image %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <img data-lazy="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
    </a>
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

An Assets field always returns an instance of [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) – essentially an array-like object – even if there's only 1 (or even 0) files in the field.

This is why things like `matrixBlock.image[0]` – or `matrixBlock.image.first()` – is needed to pull an actual asset, that you can call `getUrl()` and other related methods on.

*To output all images in an Assets field, you need to* loop *over the field:*

```
{% for image in block.image %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <img data-lazy="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

To put it all together, in this case it probably makes sense to **filter** the Matrix field using the `type` method, in order to only loop over the image blocks. This is especially useful if your Matrix block also contains other, non-image blocks – this way, you don't need the `switch` statement, and can get away with a minimal amount of code:

```
{% set imageBlocks = entry.body.type('imageFull, imageHalf, imageCouple') %}
{% if imageBlocks | length %}
    {% for block in imageBlocks %}
        {% for image in block.image %}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            <img data-lazy="{{ image.getUrl() }}" class="{{ block.type }}" />
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```